# When trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 downloaded onto an external hard drive it does not show up as a boot option

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for several years on a System76 Gazelle, but after a recent update, the OS will not boot and instead displays either a black screen or error messages. I am now trying to overwrite the OS with a newer version (Ubuntu 20.04) from an external Solid State Drive. The issue I am having is that the SSD does not appear as an option from my Aptio Setup Utility.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you make the SSD bootable? Or did you simply copy the installer .iso onto the SSD without making it bootable?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: user535733 - You might have a point, I simply downloaded ubuntu onto the SSD without taking any special steps .. keep in mind i am NOT on Windows. My understanding is that Ubuntu should boot automatically from an external device but is this not right? Thanks.

Comment: Your understanding was in error, sorry. A random .iso file on a random disk's filesystem is not bootable. Review @guiverc's tutorial links for how to properly create an Ubuntu installer from the .iso image. Note that the tutorials work with plain, cheap, common USB sticks precisely to avoid many hardware-specific issues. If your SSD is not visible in BIOS (Aptio Setup Utility), then your SSD-based method is likely a dead end, and you should borrow a USB stick from a friend. Note that System76 has a good reputation for supporting their hardware -- they may have a better solution.

Comment: If properly written to your media (so it's bootable), it will boot. You can write media to a hard disk, ssd, thumb-drive, compact-flash, in fact any device that your hardware will boot from - but it needs to be written in a bootable form; having it a file on a file-system isn't bootable (without you modifying your boot loader of installed OS/system to give you the option to boot an ISO on a file-system's which is more work than writing an ISO to boot media in my experience - but worth it for devices that don't have a working USB port for example!)

Comment: user535... and guiverc, thank you both. didn't know I needed to make the image bootable, I will try that next.

Comment: To follow up, both user535733 and guiverc were spot on, I had not made my Ubuntu file bootable. In the end I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/UAAcQVJxfPk)   This talked me through creating a bootable USB drive from a Chromebook. Then my Aptio Setup Utility recognized the removable thumb drive so I could select it and proceed from there.

Comment: I suggest posting an answer (rather than a comment - but similar in content to your last comment) to your own question to help others with the same problem in the future.